# How many US military troops are in Syria?

Tags: united-states, syria

How many US military troops are in Syria?

Are there any official statistics, claims by Russia or Syria, Or any other notable sources about this?

Comment: Russia claims untrue things all the time, so lets not go by their claims.   Assad's probably not to be trusted on this either.   You're asking for unreliable sources.

Comment: then every source is untrue and not to be trusted. can u trust on US politicians or media? can u trust  European    politicians or media?  can u trust creators of   #metoo? ... can u trust....?------------------ I dont trust any; i only want to see different sources and guess what would be true, what is the min and max, and ...

Comment: I agree with you that knowing which source to trust is difficult (and for the hard core skeptic - impossible).   I didn't say the US was trustworthy, only that Syria and Russia are very much not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official number is 503. [There are reports of 4000 from one general's press conference](https://www.defense.gov/News/Transcripts/Transcript-View/Article/1359137/department-of-defense-press-briefing-by-general-jarrard-via-teleconference-from/), the main explanation usually offered between discrepancy being temporary vs permanent troops (or, "general misspoke", you takes your bets).

> GEN. JARRARD:  So there -- we have a -- approximately 55,000 Syrian -- or 5,000 -- I'm sorry -- it's -- **I think it's a little over 4,000 U.S. troops in Syria right now that are supporting efforts in -- against Daesh, and supporting the SDF.**
>
> Q:  So you have 4,000 U.S. troops in Syria?  Because I thought the -- publicly, previously, the number was 1,000?  This would be four times -- well, it was actually 500.  But you're saying 4,000 U.S. troops are currently in Syria?
>
> **GEN. JARRARD:  I'm sorry.  I misspoke there.  There are approximately 500 troops in Syria.**
>
> (Laughter.)
>
> Q:  Because I think the accurate number is 1,000.
>
> Q:  Then why'd you ask the question if you know the answer?
>
> Q:  Well, I knew -- (inaudible).
>
> **MR. PAHON:  Idrees, as you know, the FML is 503 in Syria, and 5,262 in Iraq.  FML is 503 in Syria and 5,262 in Iraq.**
>
> (*Source: Department of Defense Press Briefing by General Jarrard via teleconference from Baghdad, Iraq; Press Operations; Major General James B. Jarrard, commander, Special Operations Joint Task Force-Operation Inherent Resolve; Eric J. Pahon, Defense Department Spokesman ; Oct. 31, 2017*)